# JQuery slideToggle should toggle for specific list item in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, slidetoggle

## Update

Use this JQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggleOne").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children(".oneContent").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

I have 3 divs with 1 unordered list and 1 div each. I am trying to implement a JQuery function such that whenever I click the button (with class toggleOne), the div (with class oneContent) associated with that div should be visible and slide Down. But, my implementation is not working. Help will be appreciated.

## JQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggleOne").click(function() {
      $(".oneContent").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
</script>
```

## HTML

```
<div class="oneDiv">
    <ul class="oneList">
      <li class="oneList_item">
        <h3>ABC</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="oneList_item">
        <button onClick={this.handleChange} class="toggleOne">
          Click Here
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="oneContent">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="oneDiv">
    <ul class="oneList">
      <li class="oneList_item">
        <h3>ABC</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="oneList_item">
        <button onClick={this.handleChange} class="toggleOne">
          Click Here
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="oneContent">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="oneDiv">
    <ul class="oneList">
      <li class="oneList_item">
        <h3>ABC</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="oneList_item">
        <button onClick={this.handleChange} class="toggleOne">
          Click Here
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="oneContent">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.oneContent {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested divs are having attribute "className" instead of "class". Change them to classes so jquery can access and perform the required function on them.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to make the change here. But, it's not working by using class too.